# Read numbers from the PHONE_STATE intent action android 9 Not working

Tags: android, phone-state-listener, android-9.0-pie

I was trying to retrieve the phone number from intent extra through onrecieve() method for the following broadcast receiver registered in manifest file.

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I can successfully able to read the phone number for all the version except android pie upgraded in my pixel 2 device. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all), app requires additional permission for reading phone number which are READ_CALL_LOG permission and the READ_PHONE_STATE permission but even after allowing these permission I still get missing permission for READ_CALL_LOG therefore I couldn't able to read the phone number. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you grant READ_PHONE_STATE and READ_CALL_LOG permissions at runtime in Android 6.0+:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions

Also, note that after granting these two permissions, you will receive ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast intent action twice; one with the EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER populated with the phone number, and another with it blank.
You can find more information here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED

Comment: I don't understand why android modifies so many things from on release to another. READ_CALL_LOG  was not needed before Pie. Why do they think it is necessary now? It is so boring...

Comment: confirmed. the second broadcast has the phone number. ridiculous.

Comment: Problem is that READ_CALL_LOG is now a permission that requires an exception to use.  Seems they moved ability to see phone number for caller ID to make it so only a handful of apps can use it.  Any workarounds?

Answer (score 6):

With the new Google Play permissions changes (i.e.post January 9, 2019 and Android Pie) none of the above works anymore.
You app will work locally or if the user downloads the APK manually but you can no longer update the app to the Play Store. Here's part of the email from Google Play.
"Hi Developers at Kishor Bapat9,    Thanks for contacting the Google Play team about your app Ekalipi Call Announcer (ECA), com.ked.ekalipi.tts.
Publishing Status
Publishing status: Rejected
After review, your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
Issue: Violation of Permissions policy  After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the requested permissions for the following reason(s):

Based on our review, we found your app's expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality {Caller ID, spam detection, and /or spam blocking}. Please remove these permissions from your app. "

Note- We have not specifically asked for these permissions. We have even tried changing the descriptions in different ways. 
CATCH 22 - If you specify the CALL_LOG permission Google Play rejects your app. If you remove the permission you cannot get the incoming call's number.

Comment: so what is the solution then? how we can publish this type of application in google play store?  can you publish your app with this permission.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

Per the docs the phone numbers given from the broadcast need extra permissions. because its like gaining access to call log info [without requesting it](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all).

> Restricted access to phone numbers Apps running on Android 9 cannot
>   read phone numbers or phone state without first acquiring the
>   READ_CALL_LOG permission, in addition to the other permissions that
>   your app's use cases require.
>
> Phone numbers associated with incoming and outgoing calls are visible
>   in the phone state broadcast, such as for incoming and outgoing calls
>   and are accessible from the PhoneStateListener class. Without the
>   READ_CALL_LOG permission, however, the phone number field that's
>   provided in PHONE_STATE_CHANGED broadcasts and through
>   PhoneStateListener is empty.
>
> To read phone numbers from phone state, update your app to request the
>   necessary permissions based on your use case:
>
> To read numbers from the PHONE_STATE intent action, you need both the
>   READ_CALL_LOG permission and the READ_PHONE_STATE permission. To read
>   numbers from onCallStateChanged(), you need the READ_CALL_LOG
>   permission only. You don't need the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

ps. Please test this. In my Broadcastreciever i now need a awful block like this:

```
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26 && intent!=null && intent.getExtras() !=null 
&& TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getExtras().getString("incoming_number"))){
                        return;
                    }
```

Comment: The only problem with that solution can be when incoming call is with private number. So the code below the block will not run.

Comment: What is returned when it's private number. Can you tell? Is it null ?

Comment: Yes - it return null. So I assume it should have some kind of counter. When first broadcast is come with null then skip run the code but run the code on the second one.