# Get incoming call number programmatically on android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I am trying to get incoming call info using broadcast receivers on android studio.
following are the methods i tried:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.IncomingCalls">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

On this receiver's intent i tried:

Method one:

```
incnumber=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

Method two:

```
final String state1 = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                incnumber=incomingNumber;
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Method Three:

```
incnumber=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

All the three methods return empty incnumber.

By the way, I am running this project on android pie, Please help me out.

Comment: is it working fine for all other versions except pie ?

Comment: I think not , I will try and revert asap

Comment: ok..Have you added this permission 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: It seems it's only for pie, it works on oreo

Comment: yep i've done that

Comment: if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26 && intent!=null && intent.getExtras() !=null 
&& TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getExtras().getString("incoming_number"))){
                        return;
                    }
try this as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739395/read-numbers-from-the-phone-state-intent-action-android-9-not-working/51850264

Comment: extra_incoming_number is depricated in Java in api level 21 and above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way...
permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Make a Broadcast receiver say ServiceReceiver assign its action in Manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
</intent-filter>
```

**ServiceReceiver.Java**

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
        }
    },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

}

Comment: Can we get the number from incoming call on android 11 without call-logs permission??? or from notification listner???