# Get incoming call number programmatically on android 10

Tags: java, android

Looking at previous [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938774/get-incoming-call-number-programmatically-on-android) for this problem are now [depreciated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER) as of api 29(Android 10). Has anyone been able to get the incoming phone number on for api 29. Apparently now to do this you need to use [CallScreeningService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, implement the class and add the necessary permission below in the manifest:

```
  <service
        android:name=".CallScreeningService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.CallScreeningService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Within `onScreenCall(Call.Details details)` you can call `details.getHandle()` which returns the telephone number of the incoming call. This will only get called if the number cannot be matched to the contact information existing on the device.

```
@Override
public void onScreenCall(Call.Details details) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if(details.getCallDirection() == Call.Details.DIRECTION_INCOMING) {
            CallResponse.Builder response = new CallResponse.Builder();
            response.setDisallowCall(false);
            response.setRejectCall(false);
            response.setSilenceCall(false);
            response.setSkipCallLog(false);
            response.setSkipNotification(false);
            details.getHandle(); //This is the calling number
            respondToCall(details, response.build());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this really work for all calls, since the documentation states "Further, only calls which are not in the user's contacts are passed for screening. " -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService#onScreenCall(android.telecom.Call.Details)

Comment: Correct this is only called when the incoming number is not in the devices Contacts list

Comment: This implementation will only fetch the Phone Numbers that are Unknown or Not saved in your Contacts. Doesn't answer the question yet completely.