# Becoming the CallScreeningService on API >= 24

Tags: java, android, service, call, callscreeningservice

I want to become the CallScreeningService on API >= 24. This should be doable as the function was implemented in 24, however the recommended usage in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService?hl=en#becoming-the-callscreeningservice) uses RoleManager (which is implemented in 29).

I tried using the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987962/how-to-bind-callscreeningservice?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493926/get-incoming-call-number-programmatically-on-android-10) however I cannot seem to set up my custom service class or my MainActivity.java. I try to run the service, which either fails and does nothing or crashes my app. I am still novice to Android app development (but moderately experienced with Java), so beginner friendly replies are appreciated.
I did get the method in the [developer.android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService?hl=en#becoming-the-callscreeningservice) to work, however it again uses >=29.

What should I write to set up my custom screening service class and MainActivity.java (at least just for onCreate())? This is what I have so far:

Manifest

```
        <service android:name="com.example.myapp.MyCallScreeningService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.telecom.CallScreeningService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

MyCallScreeningService.java

```
public class MyCallScreeningService extends CallScreeningService {
    @Override
    public void onScreenCall(Call.Details details) {
            CallResponse.Builder response = new CallResponse.Builder();
            response.setDisallowCall(false);
            response.setRejectCall(false);
            response.setSkipCallLog(false);
            response.setSkipNotification(false);
            respondToCall(details, response.build());
    }
}
```

If you choose to post code or code resources, please do so in Java. I am not familiar with Kotlin.

Edit:
Adding this:

```
public class MyCallScreeningService extends CallScreeningService {
                              .
                              .
                              .

    private MyCallScreeningBinder mCallScreeningBinder = new 
    MyCallScreeningBinder();
    private IBinder iBinder = new MyCallScreeningBinder();

    public class MyCallScreeningBinder extends Binder {
        MyCallScreeningService getService() {
            return MyCallScreeningService.this;
        }
    }
                              .
                              .
                              .
```

and (in my MainActivity):

```
    MyCallScreeningService mCallScreeningService;
    boolean bound = false;

    ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
      //line 20 below
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
      //line 20 above
            MyCallScreeningService.MyCallScreeningBinder callScreeningBinder = (MyCallScreeningService.MyCallScreeningBinder)service;
            mCallScreeningService = callScreeningBinder.getService();
            bound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            bound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyCallScreeningService.class);
        bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
```

yields the following exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.telecom.CallScreeningService$CallScreeningBinder cannot be cast to com.example.myapp.MyCallScreeningService$MyCallScreeningBinder

> at com.example.callscreen.MainActivity$1.onServiceConnected(MainActivity.java:20)

MainActivity.java line 20 is indicated by comment blocks in the last code block.
I am not sure how the compiler pulls the Android system CallScreeningBinder from my MyCallScreeningService class. I feel like if I can fix this (ie. make my onServiceConnected recognize my MyCallScreeningBinder), I will have my the service bind correctly, however I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Before 29 you cannot without implementing a full dialer app, from 29 you don't need to use neither `Intent` or `bindservice` just what you already added in your Manifest plus the rolerequest `RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_SCREENING` (Beware that if you have an Eventbus importing RoleManager can crash it in `.register` for api < 29. Is avoidable by putting `.register` in an inner class of main class) [here's a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617497/can-a-third-party-app-implement-callscreeningservice-in-android-7), hope it helps!