# How to get the incoming caller's phone number?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to get the incoming caller's phone number in my flutter app
I found this code that gives me the number in Android but for some reason, it doesn't work with flutter

I got the broadcastreceiver from here
[Access phone number of incoming calls in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66112321/access-phone-number-of-incoming-calls-in-flutter)

And this is my main

```
package com.example.docapp;
 
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
 
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
 
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
 
 
 
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String PhoneNumber = "www.this.com/callerid";
    private Intent forService;
    String  num;
    int state;
 
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Oncreate Main","MAIN MAIN MAIN");
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine){
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    forService = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
 
 
 
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(),PhoneNumber)
            .setMethodCallHandler(
                (call,result)->{
                   if(call.method.equals("getcallerid")){
 
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
 
 
                        startForegroundService(forService);
                        } else{
 
 
                        startService(forService);
                        }
 
                       result.success("this");
                    Log.d("My Activity","Method in Java");
                   }else{
                       result.notImplemented();
                   }   
                }
            );
        }
 
 
}
```

I am trying this on my phone with Android 9.

Comment: I have the same problem. I need to create an application that runs in the background which, when a call comes in, retrieves the number of the caller and displays some information from the database stored about that number. Have you succeeded in creating your application ?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you more easy solution for this with sharedPreferences and BroadcastReceiver only for android (on ios i have not many experience and not trying this yet)

Paste this code in `<application>` tag

**/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name=".ServiceReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And inside `<manifest>`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Then create in your project folder file
**/android/app/src/main/kotlin/your/package/name/ServiceReceiver.java**

With content:

```
package your.package.name;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if(incomingNumber != "" && incomingNumber != null && !incomingNumber.isEmpty()){
                    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("FlutterSharedPreferences", context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Name of SP database for flutter
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("flutter.verification_phone", incomingNumber).apply();

                    System.out.println(settings.getString("flutter.verification_phone", "NOTFOUND"));
                    System.out.println(incomingNumber);
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

And inside your dart file (where you need read this value):

```
SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await sp.reload(); //needed for getting updated value

String someVariable = "";

if(sp.containsKey('verification_phone'))
{
  someVariable = sp.getString('verification_phone')!;
}

print(someVariable);
```

Don't forget about request for permissions in dart code (I use permission_handler package)

```
await Permission.contacts.request();
await Permission.phone.request();
```