# How to save a phone number in an incoming call in Flutter

Tags: flutter, broadcastreceiver, flutter-platform-channel

I want to get the incoming caller's phone number in my flutter app.
I'm trying the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66112321/access-phone-number-of-incoming-calls-in-flutter?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer, but it doesn't work.

I have no knowledge about it at all and have not been able to find a resource with all the stages. What am I doing wrong?

The full code: https://github.com/gulsenkeskin/phone_call_demo

Comment: are you using third party for call like twilio or else or just native if does try flutter incoming callkit if does work for you.

Comment: @ArbiterChil just native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. If anyone needs it, he can look at [this](https://github.com/gulsenkeskin/phone_call_demo) link

Comment: Android is working. IOS not implemented. Please add IOS implementation also.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a solution that works for iOS. It is also said that this is not possible for iOS. :(

Comment: If you find a solution for iOS and let me know, I would be very happy :D

Comment: Did anyone solve on iOS?

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this in Flutter. To receive incoming call you should go for native, in the `number` String you will receive the incoming caller's number.

```
package com.anand.example;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;


public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  
    String number = "";
  
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        if (number != null) {
            if (number != null) {
                if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    System.out.println(number);
                    // call attended

                } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    // call ended
                    System.out.println(number);
                } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    System.out.println(number);
                    // incoming call

                }
            }
        }


    }


}
```